# How to create a tableview (5.12 )with column headers?

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

I am creating a Table using the new qml  tableview (Qt 5.12).
I am able to create a model in C++ and able to populate the model in tabular format along with scrollbar.How do I add column headers to this table?
Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0
//import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import TableModel 0.1
Rectangle {
    id:table
    border.width: 3
    border.color: 'dark blue'
    QtObject{
        id:internals
        property int rows:0
        property int col:0
        property int colwidth:0
        property var columnName:[]
    }

    function setRows(num){ internals.rows = num}
    function setCols(num){ internals.col =  num}
    function setColWidth(num){internals.colwidth = num}

    function setColNames(stringlist){
        if(stringlist.length > 1)
            internals.col = stringlist.length

    dataModel.setColumnName(stringlist);
    }

    function addRowData(stringlist){
        var len = stringlist.length

         if(len >0)
         {
             dataModel.addData(stringlist)
         }
    }

    TableModel {
        id:dataModel
    }

    TableView{
            id:tbl
            anchors.top: headerCell
            anchors.fill: parent
            //columnSpacing: 1
            //rowSpacing: 1
            clip: true

           ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{}
           ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}

            model:dataModel

            Component{
                id:datacell
                Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 20
                    color: 'white'
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: 'dark grey'
                    Text {
                        id:txtbox
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        wrapMode:                           Text.NoWrap
                        clip:                               true
                        verticalAlignment:                  Text.AlignVCenter
                        horizontalAlignment:                Text.AlignHCenter
                        text: display
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        function init(){
            console.log("Calling init")
            tbl.delegate= datacell
        }

}
```

Comment: As said in the Qt docs: _You provide title and size of a column header by adding a TableViewColumn_ so you just have to add one or more [TableViewColumn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableviewcolumn.html#details) items

Comment: @folibis that's the old TableView, OP is using the new one.

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't paid attention. What about to implementing [headerData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) in the model?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently TableView does not have headers so you should create it, in this case use Row, Column and Repeater.

On the other hand you must implement the headerData method and you must do it Q_INVOKABLE.

```cpp
class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ...
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    // ...
```

```
TableView {
    id: tableView
    model: table_model
    // ...
    Row {
        id: columnsHeader
        y: tableView.contentY
        z: 2
        Repeater {
            model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1
            Label {
                width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                height: 35
                text: table_model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                color: '#aaaaaa'
                font.pixelSize: 15
                padding: 10
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                background: Rectangle { color: "#333333" }
            }
        }
    }
    Column {
        id: rowsHeader
        x: tableView.contentX
        z: 2
        Repeater {
            model: tableView.rows > 0 ? tableView.rows : 1
            Label {
                width: 60
                height: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData)
                text: table_model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Vertical)
                color: '#aaaaaa'
                font.pixelSize: 15
                padding: 10
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                background: Rectangle { color: "#333333" }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

The complete example you find [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55610163).

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for the solution.What is modelData  in the qml file?

Comment: @anujchauhan If you notice the model of the Repeater is a number so it is equivalent to a list of 0 to n-1 where n is the number that indicates, so the data is 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 and the modelData is just that. So you do not have to define anything, modelData will be created automatically. Read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#repeaters

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyllanesc I am able to get column header now with your help.

Comment: There is one more feature that i am trying to implement.How can I select a complete  row with mouse click or on pressing enter key and on selecting the color of the row should change? Any idea on how to implement this feature?

Comment: @anujchauhan That I know not yet a selectionModel for this TableView so you'll have to implement that logic yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to make the column resizeable?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Qt 5.15, you can use a HorizontalHeaderView for column labels.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-horizontalheaderview.html

There's also VerticalHeaderView for row labeling.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-verticalheaderview.html

Comment: That would be very helpful if these objects were properly documented. Which they are not. Is there a single example of how to use them ? I've been at it since yesterday, and I'm just giving up and going back to using Row and Column.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to the QML. I came to the answer of *eyllanesc* so many times through my struggle with the *new* TableView (qt 5.12+), so I wanna thank you and share what helped me even more.
It's this video:
[Shawn Rutledge - TableView and DelegateChooser: new in Qt 5.12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GOfY1kEP2A&ab_channel=NDCConferences)
part of Qt Virtual Tech Summit 2019

[The discussed code](https://github.com/ec1oud/qps/tree/tableview-talk)

It's a bit long but he covers

- the differences between old and new TableView
- how to create *universal* model for the views
- resizable headers
- different representation per column type - DelegateChooser
- sortable columns
- column reorder