# How to make the first row fixed in QML 2.0 TableView?

Tags: qml

There is a great post on [how to add row and column header to QML 2.0 TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610163/how-to-create-a-tableview-5-12-with-column-headers), but its row header is a separate Repeater control that does not display the data from the table model.

I tried to use a similar technique using `tableView.contentX` to make the first row fixed (to make the first colum behave like row header and stay fixed when the table is scrolled):

```
TableView {

    delegate: DelegateChooser {
        role: "type"
        DelegateChoice {
            roleValue: "first"
            delegate: Text {
                x: -tableView.contentX
                text: "%1 / %2".arg(model.item.base).arg(model.item.quote)
            }
        }
```

but with no success. Setting `x` to `0` also does not take an effect.

Comment: could you please provide minimal working  and testable example that represents your problem?