# Qt QML TableView Header not displaying

Tags: c++, qt, qml, tableview

I have a simple sample project at https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/TableView which demonstrate the problem.

I have included below what I believe is the relevant source, but the remainder is available in the project link above or I can edit and include more if useful.

My table data is showing and I was thinking I just needed to define headerData in my C++ model class to have the table header show up, but it remains hidden.

What do I need to change so the table header shows up and allows me to sort the rows by clicking in a column header?

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

import Backend 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    id:      root
    visible: true

    width:  768
    height: 450

    minimumWidth:  768
    minimumHeight: 450

    property string backendReference: Backend.objectName

    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView

        clip: true

        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10

        hoverEnabled: false

        TableView {
            id: modelResults

            model: Backend.modelResults.list

            delegate: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 18

                Text {
                    text: display
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

modeldata.cpp

```
#include "modeldata.h"

//
// ModelList
//
ModelList::
ModelList( QObject* parent )
    : QAbstractTableModel (parent )
{
}



int
ModelList::
rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
   int size = mList.size();

   return size;
}



int
ModelList::
columnCount( const QModelIndex & ) const
{
   return 2;
}




QVariant
ModelList::
data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const
{
    const ModelItem modelItem = mList.at( index.row() );

    QVariant result = QVariant();

    if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole )
    {
        if ( index.column() == 0 )
        {
          result = QVariant( QString( modelItem.population ) );
        }
        else
        {
          result = QVariant( QString::number( modelItem.averageAge ) );
        }
    }
    else if ( role == Qt::DecorationRole )
    {
        qDebug() << "decorate 1";
    }

    return result;
}



QVariant
ModelList::
headerData( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role ) const
{
    if ( section == 0 )
        return QVariant( QString( "Population" ) );
    else
        return QVariant( QString( "Average Age" ) );
}



int
ModelList::
size() const
{
    return mList.size();
}



const QList<ModelItem>&
ModelList::
list() const
{
    return mList;
}



void
ModelList::
removeAt( int index )
{
    if ( index < 0 || index >= mList.size() )
        return;

    beginRemoveRows( QModelIndex(), index, index );
    mList.removeAt( index );
    endRemoveRows();

    emit sizeChanged();
}



void
ModelList::
add( const QString& population, const int averageAge )
{
    ModelItem item;

    item.population = population;
    item.averageAge = averageAge;

    add( item );
}



void
ModelList::
add(const ModelItem& item)
{
    const int index = mList.size();

    beginInsertRows( QModelIndex(), index, index );
    mList.append( item );
    endInsertRows();

    emit sizeChanged();
}



void
ModelList::
reset()
{
    if ( mList.isEmpty() )
        return;

    beginRemoveRows( QModelIndex(), 0, mList.size() - 1 );
    mList.clear();
    endRemoveRows();

    emit sizeChanged();
}



//
// ModelResults
//
ModelResults::ModelResults(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    mList = new ModelList( this );

    qRegisterMetaType<ModelItem>("ModelItem");
}

ModelList* ModelResults::list() const
{
    return mList;
}

void ModelResults::reset()
{
    mList->reset();
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67716048/6622587

Comment: TableView does not come with headers, since Qt 5.15 you can use item HorizontalHeaderView and VerticalHeaderView to set the headers, for previous versions you have to build it yourself.